# Prove $\ AA^t $ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\ A $ be a real matrix. Prove that  $\ A \cdot A^t $ is diagonaziable.

This is the only info given. Now I understand that $\ A \cdot A^t $ is a symmetric matrix because

$\ [AA^t]_{ij} = [A]_i^r \cdot [A^t]_j^c = [A]^r_i \cdot [A]^r_j = [A^t]_i^c \cdot [A]^r_j = [A]_j^r \cdot [A^t]_i^c = [AA^t]_{ji} $

and I found [this](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/eigen/eigen.html) document where it says symmetric matrices has $\ n$ eigenvalues (not necessarily distinct) but how can I know if there is an invertible matrix $\ P $ that diagonalize $\ A $ ?

Thanks

Comment: In the same document : "There exists a set of n eigenvectors, one for each eigenvalue, that are mututally orthogonal"

Comment: Thanks it is just that no proof there..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A.A^t$ being symmetric, it is diagonalizable in an orthonormal basis (spectral theorem). That is, the eigenvectors are orthogonal (and can be normalized to 1). In other words, $$A.A^t=P^t.D.P$$
where $D$ is diagonal and $P$ verifies $$P^t.P=I$$
Here $I$ is the identity. So $P^t=P^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

It is not automatic. The fact that a symmetric matrix $B$ is diagonalizable depends on two facts:

- all eigenvalues of $B$ are real
- the orthogonal of an eigenspace is invariant by $B$

Then you start with an eigenvalue and a one-dimensional eigenspace, and then the orthogonoal of said eigenspace is invariant, and now you can again find an eigenvalue and a one-dimensional eigenspace. The process continues until you exhaust the $n$ dimensions.

What the above achieves is that you obtain a basis of eigenvectors, which is precisely what diagonalization is. Actually, you can obtain an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, which tells you that you can diagonalize $B$ using a unitary (i.e., an orthogonal matrix in this case).

Answer (score 3):

$(AB)^T=B^TA^T$.  $\therefore (AA^T)^T=(A^T)^TA^T=AA^T$

Thus $AA^T$ is symmetric. And symmetric matrices are diagonalizable.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that a [symmetric matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix) is always diagonalizable by spectral theorem.

Answer (score 1):

> symmetric matrices has $\ n$ eigenvalues (not necessarily distinct) but how can I know if there is an invertible matrix $\ P $ that diagonalize $\ A $ ?

"$n$ eigenvalues (not necessarily distinct)" or, as I like to call it, "$n$ eigenvalues if counted with geometric multiplicity", means *exactly* that there is some basis of $\Bbb R^n$ for which the linear map associated with $AA^t$ is diagonal: it's any linearly independent collection of $n$ eigenvectors, which the part "$n$ eigenvalues (not necessarily distinct)" tells us exists.